# How to remove generated labels from a list

Tags: c#

I'm making a hangman game Visual Studio. Each time the user fills in a new word to guess my program generates the correct number of labels. But it doesn't remove the labels from the previous word. Does anyone know how I can remove all generated labels before I generate them again?

I've tried multiple things but didn't get any wiser.

```
//this is how I create a single label//
public void CreateSingleLabel(int width, int heigth, int left, int top, int font)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Size = new Size(width, heigth);
    label.Location = new Point(left, top);
    label.Text = "_";
    label.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", font);
    this.Controls.Add(label);
    label.Parent = gbStatus;
    listLabels.Add(label);
}

//this loop creates the correct number of labels according to the word to guess' length//
public void CreateLabels(int width, int heigth, int left, int top, int number, int font)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        CreateSingleLabel(width, heigth, left+i*width, top, font);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the user guess characters and not words in a hangman game?

Comment: In 'CreateLabels', start by calling: listLabels.Clear();

Comment: The user can create the word to guess itself, It's kind off a multiplayer game. After filling in the word it automatically hides the word. The second player now has to guess the word.